# Why could JTextPane::setText throw an Array Out of Bounds Exception?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, jeditorpane

Why could be a possible reason for:

```
JTextPane p = new JTextPane();
p.setText("hello");
```

The exact code is rather long. So I'm not sure what parts I must show here.

It's something like:

```
Tab t = new Tab(jp1);
t.editortxt.setText("hello");
```

`Tab` extends `JPanel` and has in its constructor:

```
editortxt = new JTextPane();
```

i.e., `editortxt` is a property of `Tab`.

It throws this:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:371)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:384)
```

I mean why would something so abstract throw when I use its own API?

Comment: Nothing because you're not showing us the relevant part of the code which throws this exception.

Comment: @ZouZou, this was the exact line of code where the debugger stopped. What other part do you think is missing?

Comment: Impossible, the error is somewhere else. This two lines can't throw this exception. I don't know what your code looks like, but you're trying to access an element in your arrayList (maybe using indexOf ?).

Comment: @learner Can't be. **Look at the trace**.

Comment: is this a relevant code fragment?

Comment: The only way I could see this line of code throwing this exception is if you did something like this `setText(someStringArray[10])` where 10 is out of bounds.

Comment: could you post the full stack trace? it should show who is calling ArrayList.get().

Comment: I've put more code, but if that isn't sufficient, **I'll surely put what you ask**.

Comment: @learner, now this question makes good. I have voted for reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Verify are you passing correct index to `ArrayList.get()` method. It looks you are accessing  the element from `ArrayList` that have size is zero.